# "page-break-before: always" not working as intended after updating chrome from v97 to v98

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, page-break-before

https://cbbanalytics.com/stats/27694/games/1864019/overview - `page-break-before` is not working as intended on this page following chrome update from v97 to v98. In the screenshot below:

[image]

The highlighted `<h3>` element has the class `print-break`, which simply adds the CSS style `page-break-before: always`. However, when we pull up the print window (CMD+P on mac) and set `Margins: None`, the print break is not correct on chrome v98. On a colleague's laptop that still has Chrome v97 and the page-break-before works just fine.

[image]

We're not sure if this an issue with Chrome v98 or with our site's CSS and html. I created a simple html file with just a few `<p>` tags and a page-break-before and the page break worked fine for me locally in chrome. Quite frankly, it seems like chrome is miscalculating the page size for print, it is just so strange that the page break starts at the bottom of the previous page... Changing `Margins:` from `None` to either `Default` or `Minimum` does resolve the issue on this page, however there are many pages on our site where the `page-break-before` is buggy regardless of print margins.

Comment: can confirm this also happens with `page-break-after: always` .... quite annoying.  your margin fix didn't work for me.  my workaround is to get users to use that latest firefox.

Comment: I'm hoping if it's a chrome issue that it will resolve itself over the coming days / weeks. I will check it on firefox and other browsers, that is a good idea

Comment: see (2) in my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Meh Option - Changing **Margins:** from **None** to either **Default** or **Minimum** seems to resolve our issue... We prefer **None** for saving pages on our site to PDF without a white border around the page, however **Default** looks just fine otherwise and we can use this.

(2) Better Option - Adding `width: 100.25%` to the div with class `controller-navbar-container`  fixes this issue on this page and on every other page on the site as well. I am not sure why this is the case.

Comment: Weird! Just width:100% fixed my issue probably because it already has margins